# Call stack of shell commands

Tags: shell

When I consecutively issue multiple commands which create a new shell, e.g.

```
zsh
screen
su user2
mc
sudo su
mc
```

**Is there a command to show the “call stack”, i.e. a list of the commands which have not finished but created a new shell?**

I might have issued some other commands among them, so the shell history won’t help. Moreover, I might have switched users and shells as shown in the above example.

I know I can find this information using the tree view in `htop` but can I get it directly using a command?

Comment: Those aren't subshells, but full processes. "Subshell" means a very particular thing re. the shell's environment, see e.g. [Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html#Command-Execution-Environment)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for your notice, I corrected my question. I was misled by the warning of the second `mc` instance: “Subshell support will be disabled.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pstree` (from [PSmisc](http://psmisc.sourceforge.net/)) for this:

```
pstree -s $$
```

The `-s` option shows the parents of the specified process identifier, and `$$` is the current process’s identifier. `pstree` also shows the children of the specified process identifier, so you’ll end up with something along the lines of

```
systemd───systemd───gnome-terminal-───zsh───pstree
```

(with `screen`, `sudo`, `su`, `mc` etc. in your case).

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
ps -t $(tty)
```

where

- `tty` will return your current tty (I assume you are in interactive session).
- `$( tty)` will bring output in command line.
- `ps -t` will list all process related to the **t**ty.

you can add `ps` flag you like. (e.g.)

```
ps -t $(tty) -o stime,etime,args
```

Comment: Fun with `tsort`: `ps -t $(tty) -oppid=,pid= | tsort | xargs -n1 ps -o pid=,comm= -p`